# How can I rezise a subview inside of an UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

My app is built like this (i cannot post images)

```
UIViewController  
|  
|----UIView  
     |  
     |----UIScrollView   
          |  
          |----UIView (here are added my buttons, called contentView)
```

I would like to add buttons dinamically, depending on WebService response. I add these buttons programatically and it goes well, but the views lack space. To acomplish that goal, I have to resize the view in order to show correectly these new icons, but I cannot get the desired effect. What should I do to do this? Please, pardon my poor English xD.

== EDIT ==

Here is the code where I am adding some UISwitch to the contentView

1. UISwitch *switchDebito=[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(260,
   1080+(cantidadNotificacionesEnconrtadas * 35), 50, 35)];
2. [switchDebito setOn:notification.NotificationDebit];
3. [self.contentView addSubview:switchCredito];

In line 1 I create the switch, increasing its height eventually (not really important)
Line 2 is pointless
Line 3: here we add the switch to the contentView

Comment: Please share screen shot of your output and expected output.

Comment: Answer detect on how many button you are adding and after adding one button how much size to want to increase

Comment: Share some code with us. how you are adding it?

Comment: post edited with code Nilesh Mahajan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone looking araund with the same question, just set the frame of the scroll bigger and then set the content view frame and voila!!

Answer (score 1):

Overwrite viewWillLayoutSubViews method in your view controller and set the content view frames inside it

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubViews {
     [super viewWillLayoutSubViews];
      //set your frames here
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with 'set your frames here' ? Sorry